# Register selected variables for external html template and get the result in variable

Tags: php, templates

I am working on a solution that needs to load an external template (html+php) file and need to supply certain values to be printed through it.

For security reason I do not want to let all the variables in current scope be accessed in template.

I want all the rendered result from template should be returned as a string to be stored in a variable instead of being directly printed to page body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

```
// start output buffering, nothing will be printed out to the screen from now.
ob_start();

// this will not print to the screen as usual because of ob_start().
include('my/template/file.php');

// ob_get_contents() will return everything that should have been sent to the screen since ob_start was called.
$template_contents = ob_get_contents();

$final_contents = doMyStringReplaceFunction($template_contents, $arrayOfSubstitutions);
```

You can also to this at once but supplying a callback to on_start();

```
ob_start('myCallbackFunction');
include('my/template/file.php');

// this will pass the contents of the include to myCallbackFunction() then echo to the screen.
ob_end_flush();
```